# AutoCompleteTextView in ListView

Tags: android

I have got a `ListView` contains info about radio stations. It consists of several custom items (`TextView` + `CheckBox`) and embedded `AutoCompleteTextView` at the top. My problem is that I implemented getView() method of `ListView's` `Adapter` probably incorrect, because It scrolls up and down well only if I don't select `AutoCompleteTextView`, because after that action I get NullPointerException. To be clearer, here is a snippet of my Custom Adapter code:

```
class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RadioStations> {

    private Activity a;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private View searchView; 
    private ArrayAdapter<RadioStation> mAdapter;

    public ImageAdapter(Activity act, RadioStation[] objects) {
        super(act, 0, objects);
        a = act;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) a.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<RadioStation>(RadioStationListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mStations);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GETTING VIEW[" + position + "]");
        final TextView NameOfStation;
        CheckBox FavouriteFlag;

        if(position == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Making AutoCompleteTextView");
            searchView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_view, null);
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.Seacrh_field)).setAdapter(mAdapter);
            ((AutoCompleteTextView)searchView.findViewById(R.id.Seacrh_field)).setOnItemClickListener(
                new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,  int position, long id) {                            
                        ...
                    }
                }
            );
            searchView.setFocusable(true);
            return searchView;
        }
        if(convertView == null || convertView == searchView){
            Log.w(TAG, "Convert view is null");
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_list_item, null);                 
        }   

        final RadioStation station = getItem(position-1);

        NameOfStation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_of_chanel);
        FavouriteFlag = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);

        if(NameOfStation == null)
            Log.d(TAG, "Name of station is null!!!!!!!!!");
        NameOfStation.setText(station.toString());
        FavouriteFlag.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
            }
        });

        FavouriteFlag.setFocusable(false);


        return convertView;
    }
```

}

So if anybody see my misstake I would be glad to take your advice. By the way I get NullPointerException when I try to put text into `NameOfStation` and It`s because convertView remain to be search view despite on condition

`if(convertView == null || convertView == searchView)
                          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_list_item, null);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the search view should be part of the list and should also scroll with it, you can set it using [addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) of ListView class to add a view to the top of the list which is not managed by the adapter. Perhaps this makes the logic of you adapter easier as it only has to handle the "real" list items.

If the search view should always be at the top of the list and shouldn't scroll with it, you can simply move it above the ListView in you layout file. This might be the better user experience.

Comment: Thank for your response, but if I use this approach I meet with another problem: in my on resume method I always call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged of ListView adapter. And I cast it to `BaseAdapter`. Now when I add header view I get ClassCastException. Have you any thoughts about how to solve this problem

Comment: I answered on my question myself. I just needed to cast `ListView`'s adapter to `HeaderViewListAdapter` class then call `getWrappedAdapter` method and only then cast it to `BaseAdapter`. Rather long actions, but app works. Thank you so much, you are true friend)))